# Vue.js - Element UI - Form already filled in text

Tags: forms, vue.js, element-ui

I am using Vue Element UI to create UI forms based on my data (hosts), creating a inline form for each host.
My problem is, how do i set the 'value', the already filled in text, inside the input box to my host's corresponding value?

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        formInline: {
          hostname: [],
          role: []
        },
        hosts : [
          {
            id:1,
            hostname: "toy1",
            role: "compute",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            hostname: "toy2",
            role: "storage",
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            hostname: "toy3",
            role: "storage",
          }
          ]
      };
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.3.5/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(host,index) in hosts" v-if="host.roles !==''" :key="host.id" >
<el-form :inline="true" :name="hosts.id" :model="formInline" class="demo-form-inline">
  <el-form-item label="Hostname">
    <el-input v-model="formInline.hostname[index]" placeholder="host.hostname" :value="host.hostname"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
  <el-form-item label="Role">
    <el-select v-model="formInline.role[index]" placeholder="host.role"  :value="host.role">
      <el-option label="Compute" value="compute"></el-option>
      <el-option label="Storage" value="storage"></el-option>
    </el-select>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
</div>
    <button>Apply</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, what error are you having ?

Comment: no error, but the value will not be filled in the form. I thought i can use :value instead of v-model, but the el-select will not work well...

Comment: oh okay, why can't u just put/initialize the 'hosts' array in formInline.hostname ? that way you can do your loop with formInline.hostname and still be able to use v-model to keep the values in sync.

Comment: in my code, the host array will be a dynamic array return from api call, is that i must initialize the formInline.hostname?

Comment: yeah it doesnt matter, it would work...just fetch the array from the backend and store it in formline.hostname. u can then do ur v-for loop with the formline.hostname. cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

```
formInline: {
  hostname: ['toy1', 'toy2', 'toy3'],
  role: ['compute', 'storage', 'storage']
}
```

your input model binding directly with index of formInline. so, that required data for binding.